# Realm exception when calling from iOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin, realm

In my Xamarin Forms project, when I call a function that uses Realm (the project with common code) from iOS project, I get the following exception. From Android project it works fine. The exception occurs when trying to get the Realm instance with `Realm.GetInstance()`. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

```
{System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Realms.SharedRealmHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) Realms.SynchronizationContextEventLoopSignal:GetCurrentSynchronizationContext ()' while running in aot-only mode. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/ for more information.

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_to_ftnptr(object)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Realms.SynchronizationContextEventLoopSignal.install_eventloop_callbacks(Realms.SynchronizationContextEventLoopSignal/get_eventloop,Realms.SynchronizationContextEventLoopSignal/post_on_event_loop,Realms.SynchronizationContextEventLoopSignal/release_eventloop)
  at Realms.SynchronizationContextEventLoopSignal.Install () [0x0003b] in /Users/realm/workspace/realm_realm-dotnet_PR-1723/Realm/Realm/Native/SynchronizationContextEventLoopSignal.cs:122 
  at Realms.NativeCommon.Initialize () [0x00119] in /Users/realm/workspace/realm_realm-dotnet_PR-1723/Realm/Realm/Native/NativeCommon.cs:91 
  at Realms.SharedRealmHandle..cctor () [0x00000] in /Users/realm/workspace/realm_realm-dotnet_PR-1723/Realm/Realm/Handles/SharedRealmHandle.cs:124 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Realms.RealmConfiguration.CreateRealm (Realms.Schema.RealmSchema schema) [0x000b4] in /Users/realm/workspace/realm_realm-dotnet_PR-1723/Realm/Realm/RealmConfiguration.cs:153 
  at Realms.Realm.GetInstance (Realms.RealmConfigurationBase config, Realms.Schema.RealmSchema schema) [0x0003f] in /Users/realm/workspace/realm_realm-dotnet_PR-1723/Realm/Realm/Realm.cs:138 
  at Realms.Realm.GetInstance (Realms.RealmConfigurationBase config) [0x00000] in /Users/realm/workspace/realm_realm-dotnet_PR-1723/Realm/Realm/Realm.cs:80 
  at Realms.Realm.GetInstance (System.String databasePath) [0x00000] in /Users/realm/workspace/realm_realm-dotnet_PR-1723/Realm/Realm/Realm.cs:67 
  at NumeropakettiMobile.LocalDB+<UpdateDB>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00023] in /Users/lasse/Code/numeropaketti_mobile/NumeropakettiMobile/NumeropakettiMobile/LocalDB.cs:17 }
```